# Calling functions & scripts in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

How do call a script to a function and vica versa in Matlab/Octave?

```
function mean_DNA_Microarray = Calc_mean_DNA_Microarray(M)
   M = DNA_Microarray 
   mean_DNA_Microarray = M - ones(5,25)*mean(M(:,25)) 
end
```

The response is

> error: invalid call to script
>   C:\Users\Nacho\Documents\Matlab\DNA_Microarray.m error: called from:
>   error:   C:\Users\Nacho\Documents\Matlab\Calc_mean_DNA_Microarray.m at
>   line 3, column 3

Now this will work if I call `DNA_Microarray` a function, but the problem requires that it remain as a script.

Comment: ?  Did you tried typing the name of the function/script  ?

Comment: Here is the code I've written:                               function mean_DNA_Microarray = DNA_Microarray

C = M - ones(5,25)*mean(M(:,25))
end                                                               where DNA_Microarray is the name of the script I'm trying to call

Comment: Edit your question with the code, without linebreaks it doesnt make sense

Comment: But you are using DNA_microarray as a function. If you use it as a function, it needs to be a function.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you are not defining your function correctly, as the function does not know what  `M` is (unless it is a global vairable, but I doubt so).

In ANY programming language, you need to tell a function which variables it is going to work with. This is not Matlab specific. In Matlab you will do it so:

```
function mean_DNA_Microarray = Calc_mean_DNA_Microarray(M)  % Look! we are telling him what M is!
    mean_DNA_Microarray = M - ones(5,25)*mean(M(:,25)) 
end
```

Then you want to all the function from somewhere else you would need to just type its name and pass in the *arguments*, in this case what inside the function is going to be called `M`

```
clear;
clc;
% Test code
Mnameoutofthefunction=rand(100,100);
DNAmean = DNA_Microarray(Mnameoutofthefunction); % here we are calling it!
```

Remember to save the function as functionname.m , in your case DNA_Microarray.m , else Matlab wont know which one it is.

But I HIGHLY recommend you to read a book about Matlab or just about programming in general, as it seems like you could benefit from some basic introduction.

Following @am304 suggestion, here you can find nice tutorials:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_center/tutorials/

**EDIT**  What you want to do is create a function as follows:

```
function mean_DNA_Microarray = Calc_mean_DNA_Microarray(M)  % Look! we are telling him what M is!
    mean_DNA_Microarray = M - ones(5,25)*mean(M(:,25)) 
end
```

And then, inside your function DNA_Microarray call  Calc_mean_DNA_Microarray with the input M

Comment: Shouldn't `C` be replaced by `mean_DNA_Microarray`?

Comment: @Divakar is correct, `C` should be replaced by `mean_DNA_Microarray` in the code, otherwise it won't work. To follow on the advice from Ander Biguri, I would suggest going through the tutorial at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_center/tutorials/.

Comment: @Divakar my bad, I just rewrited the code here and forgot to change that. Thanks!

Comment: @Raymond Please, realize that is very dificult to understand anything if you write it in a comment. Edit your original answer

Comment: @Raymond thats because you shoudlnt write code in comments. EDIT YOUR ORIGINAL QUESTION. Click `edit` below your first original quesstion.